# Working on a PHP web project from GitHub in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, web-applications

I am collaborating on a PHP project with a colleague using GitHub. I want to work on the code in Eclipse, and test the web pages within Eclipse. I have installed eGit and PDK in Eclipse. I think I have imported the project into Eclipse properly. Now I want to test some of the pages in Eclipse so I can get an idea of whats going on. Do I have to install a web server on my machine, or is there something built in to Eclipse for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDT plugin of Eclipse doesn't include a web server with it, you can check the [main PDT page](http://www.zend.com/en/company/community/pdt/) where it instructs you to install a web server to run and debug your code.

Newer versions of PHP do include a a [built in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) to run code so, technically you don't need a web server, but you should probably set up Apache/Nginx to mimic what your code would run on in a production environment for less deployment headaches.

A quick and easy web server would be [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). XAMPP is easy to set up and run and comes with Apache, MySQL, PHP and some other stuff useful for setting up your development enviornment.

Comment: Man, the whole purpose of Eclipse was supposed to be eliminating the need to set up a web server. Oh well, guess I'll just use good ole Notepad++.

Comment: There are better IDEs, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have the hots for Eclipse, but this is web development, not desktop development. If you want to properly test a web application, it is better to use the most popular browsers to test it in, such as IE, Firefox and Chrome.

You will need a web server, yes, here are a few :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

Note that those are for windows, but some of them are multi platform, such as XAMPP.

Also, for a web development IDE, I recommend PHPStorm, you can try it for free here :

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/